# Advanced File Copy & Move Utility for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation

Are there any Powerful File Copy and Move Utility for Ubuntu 14.04 instead of Ubuntu default file copy utility with the following features:

- Add or remove files and folders to its queue for easy dealing with mass file operations.
- Pause/Resume or Skip
- Ability to be set as default File copy manager

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Ultra Copier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/). which is based on QT and provide advance features.(Under GPL3)

Install by (available on [universe repository](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/base/ultracopier) for Ubuntu 14.04):

```
sudo apt-get install ultracopier
```

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

Comment: It won't work with Ubuntu 14.04 when ultracopier open with a bug and not really working. When try to change settings it automatically closed due to a bug.

Comment: i can't open it because there is no launcher on dash. Then i opened it from terminal. It is always open with a error ** unable to open n writing the file:no such a file or directory** and every time when i try to add file to copy app crashed.

Comment: @sameermw You can open from (press Alt+F2 and then) `ultracopier`. You can also make custom .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`