# It's 2018. Does Linux in general (any distro) have a good file copying utility

Tags: 18.04, filemanager, copy

I have looked around and only found old posts from 2010-2013. The only apparent 'worth while' solution I've found is ultracopier mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485355/advanced-file-copy-move-utility-for-ubuntu) which after installing doesn't work, at least for me. It's 2018, are there really no good solutions for file copying out there?. I'm talking about at least any of the following features (hopefully all of them):

1- Pause copy

2- Copy queue management and reordering

3- ACTUAL remaining time estimation, cause I'm using nautilus and after it says "it's done" most of the time you can't extract the pen drive cause "it's still writing"

I'm using 18.04

Comment: Can you elaborate on it "doesn't work"? ie when you call `ultracopier` from the terminal which error messages come up? Perhaps there is an easy fix.... Or did you have any error messages downloading the `.tar` file, or extracting it, or installing it? Was there a checksum file that you checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ultracopier](https://ultracopier.first-world.info/) works with Ubuntu 18.04:

[image: ultracopier ubuntu 18.04.png]

If you have a problem installing or operating it you can contact the developer directly at: ultracopier@first-world.info

Comment: I had a couple of issues using ultracopier, but finally managed to do it after a couple of restarts and googling around. Also had to add it to startup applications otherwise it wouldn't show in the gnome panel. Thanks anyways, I couldn't get it to work last time I used it in 16.04, so I guess it's better in 18

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a good GUI solution, but learning to use `dd` or even just `cp` in the terminal will solve all the problems you listed. It's extremely simple and fast. It's probably the reason a good GUI file copier is hard to find: file copying is very simple and doesn't need a GUI.

Comment: This is not a solution.Although I like the console and find it incredibly useful, this would be an alternative if I had cron job to do some copying. I am a developer so I use the console day to day, and while copying and linking files is certainly useful sometimes I want to perform a simpler task like copying a movie to a friend's flash drive, or simply managing my media files and there a GUI tool would be a lot more useful. That's why I think that modern file managers that bring a lot of features like dual panel, multiple renames, etc etc, should have at least copy pause, even wintendo has it

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options.  If you are copying just a few files and they are relatively small, use 'cp'.  You shouldn't need to pause copying for even a fairly large number of small files anyway (you probably can't hit CTL-C fast enough to stop the copying).  If you have very large files, you might instead try 'rsync' or 'cp', and put the copying into the background, e.g.:

cp somefile.iso /dev/sdb1/somedirectory/ &

The "&" moves the copying operation to the background so you can continue to use the terminal window for other tasks.  A similar way is to use the 'cat' command (concatenate. It works even if not actually concatenating multiple files into one, however).  E.g.:

cat somefile.iso > /media/me/usbdevice/  (copies to a USB key mounted at /media/me/usbdevice, and keeps the same name, e.g., somefile.iso).

If you have a lot of files, or several very large files, consider using 'find' and 'cpio' together - this is a very efficient combination that is excellent not only for copying large files, but also for making backups and other tasks that might involve hundreds or thousands of files.  For example, assume you are in a directory /home/me/mystuff and it has hundreds of subdirectories and thousands of files.  To back it up to a flash drive mounted at /media/me/usbkey, use:

find . -depth -print | cpio -pvdaum /media/me/usbkey/

These two programs together are very fast and very complete.  It's also a lot faster than a recursive cp (e.g., cp -r * /media/me/usbkey/).

If you really *must* have a progress indicator, you can use the "pv" utility that is found (or installable) on most distributions.  It tracks the progress of data moving through a pipe (|) operation.  There are a lot of options (I use -tpreb /devicename when creating disk images, but for files, you might find something like the following (which tracks progress of a concatenation (copy) operation on a file:

pv thebigfile.ext | cat thebigfile.ext > somedestination

Here, "somedestination" might be a file on another device, like "/media/me/usbdevice/testbigfile.ext".  Note that if your machine is reasonably modern, and if the file is fairly small (under a few megabytes), the result will be the transfer speed but the ">" progress indicators will probably never get a chance to update past the first one.

Your comment that you can't extract a USB key because it's not actually finished is caused by the write delays of the device, not the copy commands.  You can get past that by using 'fsync' with the file handle, to verify that the write operation are complete before you try to umount or otherwise note that the operation is actually finished.  Again, depending on the device, that may take a while - if it's a critical problem for you, you may want to mount the target device (like the USB key) on write-through mode.  This is not for a beginner - consult the 'man mount' pages for details.

Finally, regarding your comment about copy queue management: files are copied in the order given, or the order determined by wildcard replacement if you are using wildcards.  If you want something that, for example, transfers files just once a day or twice a day, allowing you to add files to a list for transfer at the designated time such as by a cron job, then simple and fast utilities are probably not for you.  You may even have to write your own code, depending on how complex you want to get.  Your questions seems to indicate you want to put files into a list in some order, say, files A, B, C, and D, but then actually transfer them in some other order like C, B, D, A.  You gave no indication of what the reordering criteria might be (for example, size?).  Queue management programs are covered in many basic programming books (for what you seem to be describing, I'd recommend Python as it is useful for both scripting and for general programming).  You could submit filenames for later copying via an agent program (e.g."copylater.py somefile").  Then write a simple queue lister and reorganizer (perhaps giving the sequence of files to be copied, and a number for each file from 1..n, with the ability to move a file up or down in the list (e.g., "copyreorganize" with a simple text-based front end or with some list of reorganization criteria (such as size) to apply to the current list), and finally, write a small program to "commit" the copy, i.e., to actually release the results and start the copying operation (where you could also embed the pv progress bar, or do some simple computations such as summing up the file sizes and dividing by the number of bytes/second of the associated device, and possibly even changing the target from a device to an FTP transfer to a remote machine, for example).  Programs like these are relatively simple to write, but not in the space available here.